# the heatmap's color got blurry

Tags: r, colors, heatmap

I created the new data frame and tried to plot a heatmap, but it's color is blurry, only shows the red color which is the highest value 0.9. How can I fix it? Thank you!

```
# install all required packages if they are not already installed
list.of.packages <- c("ggplot2", "gridExtra", "ggExtra","ggcorrplot","dplyr","GGally")
new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)

# load all requierd packages at once
sapply(list.of.packages, require, character.only = TRUE)

Retention.df <- read.csv("https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1seZmeC_4s774P6UPT-MuAwuaRbXbx2WL", stringsAsFactors=TRUE, header=T, na.strings='')
Dput(Retention.df)

# Convert Variable_COunt from integer to factor for easier plotting of data
Retention.df$Fall_Not_Retained <- factor(Retention.df$Fall_Not_Retained)

Retention.df$Spring_Not_Retained <- factor(Retention.df$Spring_Not_Retained)

data <- Retention.df %>% select(3:13) 
data

data_new <- sapply(data, unclass)           # Convert categorical variables
data_new

ggcorr(data_new,
       hjust = 0.75,
       label = TRUE,
       label_size = 3,
       label_round = 2,
       label_alpha = TRUE,
       label_color = "black")
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include details of the packages you use and provide some test data.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help you construct a *minimal reproducible example*.

Comment: That's a good start but we still don't have access to your data since we can't read a csv file on your local hard drive.  Please post (a sample of) your data using `dput`.  The link I gave you in my first comment will help you.  Please read it and act on its advice.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1seZmeC_4s774P6UPT-MuAwuaRbXbx2WL

Comment: if not, pls access into this link to get the data, thank you

Comment: Most of the correlations are very small. Accordingly the colors are more "light grey" (the default mid color) than blue/red. You could play around with the mid color (e.g. try with "white") or provide your own `palette` instead of relying on the default gradient. Moreover, IMHO adding transparency to the labels add to the blurry look.